# The plain command doesn't work, even though the cartridge command does

Tags: tarantool

I installed tarantool cartridge following the docs:

```
tarantoolctl rocks install cartridge-cli
export PATH=$PWD/.rocks/bin/:$PATH
```

Now, according to the docs I should be able to use the `plain` and the `cartridge` commands. But I'm not able to use the `plain` command. There's no `plain` script in `.rocks/bin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are trying to create a Cartridge application using the `plain` template, according to this page: https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/2.2/book/cartridge/cartridge_dev/#application-templates

Unfortunately, this part of our doc is slightly outdated. There are no built-in templates anymore, although you still can create your own one. The right command will look like

```
cartridge create --template templates/plain ~/tmp/
```

See the latest Cartridge documentation in Github: https://github.com/tarantool/cartridge-cli#usage

Answer (score 1):

UPD: it was really present in the docs.

This is a mistake in the docs, which will be fixed. Only `cartridge` command is available.